# Trebuchet MS web font alternatives

Tags: website-design, web-fonts, font-recommendation

I have a fairly dated site that uses [Trebuchet MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet_MS) font in Latin and Cyrillic scripts. If I understand correctly, once (a decade ago) this font was available on like 95-99% of computers used for web browsing and it was ok to use it - nowadays myriads of devices (namely, Android, iOS, Linux-based devices) don't have it. In theory, it could be downloaded from Microsoft website and installed on per-computer basis, but it's not possible to redistribute it, i.e. make a web font from it.

I want to update that site and use a downloadable web font - preferably a free one. Can anyone suggest a good alternative to Trebuchet MS?

Comment: Cabin font is close to trebuchet ms if sharp corners on head are not your priority in features. its available at google fonts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing to get out there right away:
It looks like you want 1) free, 2) multiple weights, and 3) extended character sets. That's a difficult combination. With a lot of these, a combination of 1 and 3 is possible, that usually means you have to pay to get 2. If 1 and 2 are combined, it's often at the expense of 3.

Back to your question...

Trebuchet is classified as a sans-serif humanist font. Unfortunately for you, Trebuchet is a really unique font. Off of the top of my head I can't think of something that's really similar in the same way that Proxima Nova and Gotham are, or Times and Times New Roman.

[FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?filter%5btags%5d%5b%5d=humanist&filter%5bfamily_size%5d=1&filter%5bdownload%5d=all&sort=a2z) is a great resource for free fonts that can be used commercially as webfonts. The link I provided links you to all of their fonts tagged as "humanist". Out of these, I think Aller gives you the right general proportion and a variety of styles, though the letterforms for plenty of these are going to be different, and there are no Cyrillic characters that I could see. Droid Sans is a humanist font that has a lot of glyphs in it, but won't look and feel exactly like Trebuchet. Same story with Pigiarniq and Source Sans.

Another poster mentioned Google Web Fonts, so I won't repeat the exercise there.

Just for kicks, I ran Trebuchet's glyphs through [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/find?font=trebuchet) to see what it thought was similar. None of these will be free solutions, but they might be better fonts for you to work with. Identifont suggests [Prox](http://www.youworkforthem.com/font/T1362/prox?affid=143174), [FF Plus](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/fontfont/ff_plus_sans_pro/?affId=98220), [Corbel](http://www.ascenderfonts.com/font/corbel-regular.aspx), [Elsa](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/stereotypes/elsa/), and [Corpid](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lucasfonts/lf-corpid-iii/) as alternatives.

If someone comes up with a great alternative to Trebuchet, then that'll certainly be better than this answer. Otherwise, hope these resources point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 10):

[image]

I searched for an alternative, and found a perfect (?) one: **Fira Sans** (above) — a [Google web font](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Fira+Sans).

Answer (score 7):

Both [Aller](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Aller)

[image: Aller]

and [Source Sans Pro](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-sans-pro) have commonalities with Trebuchet MS,

in particular the curved tail on the lower case letter L:

[image: Source Sans Pro]

The fonts are freely available from [fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com). However, only [Source Sans Pro](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-sans-pro) is a webfont, [Aller](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Aller)
is desktop only.

For comparison, here is **Trebuchet MS Regular**:

[image: Trebuchet MS Regular]

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not free, [Trebuchet](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ascender/trebuchet/) is available as a web font.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this link! So far I've found Trebuchet only at Adobe's subscription service, which costs 35$ / year. 30$ once is definitely better :)

Comment: Don't forget it's $30 for each variant. But it will pay for itself after a bit.

Answer (score 3):

i would suggest that you go to [Google](http://www.google.com/fonts) and search for a font called "Allerta
" its is a sans-serif font like Trebuchet and has some similar letters or close enough letters.

[image]

Good day

Comment: Thanks! It definitely looks close, but there are 2 problems: (1) it's only available in single weight, which in fact looks more like medium bold to me, (2) it lacks not only the Cyrillic letters, but also even some ASCII (namely, `{`, `}`, `~`, `^`, etc).

Comment: OH, i have tested this font earlier but used basic letters and yes you are right, it looks more semi-bold. on the other hand i will look for another similar font to see if i can help you

Comment: Arimo - on google fonts seems to work perfectally and has a family of bold, italic , bold-italic and normal. hope this would help @GreyCat

Comment: Arimo seems to look *very* close to Arial, with minor differences in letters like "s", "Q" or "R". I don't feel like it's a good alternative for Trebuchet. Trebuchet seems to be more "airy", "refined", while Arial/Arimo looks like a regular neo-grotesque sans to me...

Answer (score 2):

Having Cyrillic as a requirement severely limits your options. The only comparable font I can find that has both latin and cyrillic is [Open Sans](http://opensans.com/). Stylistically it's not very close, but at least it's free

Answer (score 2):

PT Sans is similar to Trebuchet, has an open user license, and is "pan-Cyrillic". 
http://www.paratype.com/public/

They are also in [Google Web Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/#)

Answer (score 1):

Overpass.
An open typeface.

https://overpassfont.org/

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Overpass

Inspired by Interstate (as Trebuchet might have been?). These derive from U.S. Highway signage, which is well documented geometrically, rather than as typeface/font.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed that the free/libre Sawasdee font, while far from a clone, has similar features. Here's a comparison of Sawasdee Bold versus Trebuchet MS regular:

[image]

Comment: Fair try, but to me they are wildly different... every single letter is different. They have sans-serif in common but that is about it. There are wild things going on with kerning and line-heights too.